# Query for Age calculation and Date comparison inconsistent

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm doing some counts to validate a table XXX, I designed 2 queries to calculate people younger than 18 years.

The query i'm using is the following:

```sql
select count(distinct user.id) from user
left join sometable on sometable.id = user.someTableId
left join anotherTable on sometable.anotherTableId = anotherTable.id
where (sometable.id = 'x' or user.public = true) 
AND (DATE_PART('year', age(current_date, user.birthdate)) >= 0 and DATE_PART('year', age(current_date, user.birthdate)) <= 18);
```

This query is giving 5000 counts (Fake result)

but this query that is supposed to do the same:

```sql
select count(distinct user.id) from user
left join sometable on sometable.id = user.someTableId
left join anotherTable on sometable.anotherTableId = anotherTable.id
where (sometable.id = 'x' or user.public = true) 
and (user.birthdate between '2002-08-26' and current_date)
```

**SIDE NOTE:** date '2002-08-26' is because today is 2020-08-26, so I subtracted 18 years from today's date.

is giving me a different count from the first one. (This last one, is giving the correct one, since is the same that I've in another nosql database)

I would like to know what's the difference in the queries or why the counts are different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO both conditions should return the same result, what's the actual difference? Some remarks: `age(user.birthdate)`, no need for current_date, `current_date - interval '18' year` instead of a hard-coded '2002-08-26' and Standard SQL `extract(year from age(user.birthdate))` insteadof DATE_PART

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first query, you are including everyone who has not yet turned 19.

In your second query, you are excluding a bunch of 18 year old's who were born prior to 2002-08-26. For example, someone born on 2002-04-12 is still 18 years old. She won't turn 19 until 2021-04-12.

Easiest way to write in postgres is this, which provides same results as your first query:

```
    where extract(year from age(now(), birthdate)) <= 18
```

If you really want to use the format of your 2nd query, then change your line to:

```
    where (birth_date between '2001-08-27' and current_date)
```

Comment: Or just: `where extract(year from age(birthdate)) <= 18`.